# macOS and podman, port 53 issue

Tags: podman, pihole

I am trying to run Pi-hole in a podman container on macOS:

```
podman machine init
podman machine set --rootful=true
podman machine start
podman run -d --name=pihole --restart always -e TZ=Europe/Zurich -e WEBPASSWORD=admin -e FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4=192.168.1.4 -e ServerIP=192.168.1.4 -e PIHOLE_DNS_=1.1.1.1 --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -p 80:80 -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 443:443 pihole/pihole:latest
```

fails with:

```
Error: cannot listen on the TCP port: listen tcp4 :53: bind: address already in use
```

using lsof I cannot see anything listening on my port 53

Comment: Well, something *is* listening on port 53. I'm not sure how things work on a Mac. Presumably your virtual-machine which runs the containers automatically maps its ports to your laptop's. Did you check both your Mac and the vm for port 53 usage?

Answer (score 0):

**Free 53 port**

you have to kill any process using port 53 before running Pi-hole

```
sudo lsof -t -i :53 | xargs sudo kill -9
    
podman machine init
podman machine set --rootful=true
podman machine start
podman run -d --name=pihole --restart always -e TZ=Europe/Zurich -e WEBPASSWORD=admin -e FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4=192.168.1.4 -e ServerIP=192.168.1.4 -e PIHOLE_DNS_=1.1.1.1 --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -p 80:80 -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 443:443 pihole/pihole:latest
```